# Parcel -> error: unknown option '--out-dir' , error: unknown option '--out-file'

Tags: node.js, frontend, backend, pug, parcel

iam trying to use parcel and running these two commands
"watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
"build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"

when i first ran watch the **dist** word was out so gave me **error unknown option"--out-dir" **so after period of search i found out that i have to chage **"--out-dir" to "--dist-dir"** but it also gave me another error that saying **"unknown option --out-file"** and then changed out to dist but also another error saying **"--dist-file" is unknown **
can someone help me **i want to save the output of this operation into a js file called bundle **

"watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
"build:js": "parcel build ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"

**iam expecting a js file called bundle.js to in public/js to use this js file as a script in pug**

iam using **parcel v2 cause v1 has deprecated**